# How to use Bash command line to curl an API with token and payload as parameters

Tags: bash, curl, parameters, azure-batch

I am novice and first timer to bash. Trying to run bash under command line to invoke an API, by passing token and payload received from two different APIs and are set as parameters. Below is my command. I am trying to add this bash script to a task in AzureBatch service job.

It has 3 curl requests,

1. First one (**Line#1 in the code snippet below**)- gets payload by
   calling an API. ---- This is working fine, I am able to verify the
   payload using the echo statement following the first curl command.
2. Second one(**Line#3 in the code snippet below**) - gets token by
   calling the token provider ----- This is working fine as well,
   verified using the echo statement.
3. Third one (**Line#5 in the code snippet below**),This is the problematic command. I am trying to pass the token and payload received from the above two commands and the curl is not able to resolve them.

both token and payload or not resolving to their values..

**My Bash COmmand**

```
/bin/bash -c 
"payload=$(curl --location --request GET 'http://url/OutreachData')

 && echo -e \"The value of payload is: "'$payload'"\" 

&& token=$(curl --location --request POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<<tenantId>>/oauth2/v2.0/token' --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode 'client_id=<<clientId>>' --data-urlencode 'scope=api://<<applicationId>>/.default' --data-urlencode 'client_secret=<<clientSecret>>' --data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' --data-urlencode 'Audience=api://<<applicationId>>'|jq -j '.access_token')

 && echo -e \"value of token is "'$token'"\n\" 

&& result=$(curl --location --request POST 'https://url/api/<<Resource>>' --header 'accept: */*'  --header 'Content-Type: application/json'  --header 'Authorization: Bearer '"'$token'" --data-raw "'$payload'") 

&& echo -e \"Result is "'$result'"\""
```

**This is how the third Curl is resolving to, payload and token are not getting replaced as we can see in the authorization header and data-raw elements**

++ curl --location --request POST https://url/api/ --header 'accept: */*' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer ' --data-raw ''''''''

Comment: This code is a mess, and not formatted for easy reading here.  I understand you want to use `&&` to sequence your commands, but it makes it super hard for us to read.  Please simplify your code, split it on multiple lines and format it using the `{}` icon in the editor.  See [mcve].

Comment: You put `"'$payload'"`.  If you have a variable `'$payload'`, the single quotes prevent the variable from being resolved.

Comment: @Nic3500 Thanks for taking out time to read through the question. I have formatted the command, hope it is readable now?

Comment: @Nic3500 Regarding "'$payload'",  I have added "double quotes followed with single quote" for the variable because the entire command is wrapped in a string as you could see in the code block above. I have tested this using echo command (please refer to echo cmds in lines #2&4, they successfully print the value.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to explicitly run this with `bash -c` unless you are in a very constrained environment where you simply cannot run Bash by any other means.

The immediate problem is that code like

```
bash -c "echo "'$token'" && true"
```

ends up with `$token` being single-quoted in the shell which you run `bash -c` from. But the blazingly obvious fix is to not have this complex quoting in the first place.

```
payload=$(curl --location --request GET 'http://url/OutreachData')
echo "The value of payload is: '$payload'"

token=$(curl --location --request POST \
  'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<<tenantId>>/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    --data-urlencode 'client_id=<<clientId>>' \
    --data-urlencode 'scope=api://<<applicationId>>/.default' \
    --data-urlencode 'client_secret=<<clientSecret>>' \
    --data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
    --data-urlencode 'Audience=api://<<applicationId>>' |
  jq -j '.access_token')
echo "value of token is "'$token'"

result=$(curl --location --request POST \
    'https://url/api/<<Resource>>' --header 'accept: */*' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer '"$token" \
    --data-raw "$payload") 
echo "Result is "'$result'"
```

If your current shell is not Bash and you need these commands to be run in Bash, a simpler workaround is to put the script in a here document, which drastically simplifies the quoting needs (or if this is in an interactive session, just run `bash` and run these commands at the interactive Bash prompt, then `exit` when you no longer want to be in Bash).

Comment: Yes, It is a constrained environment. I have to run this through command line, I cannot create any files on the node. But agree, shell script will be much easier and I have no issues with that approach. I must use /bin/bash -c